# How to use Visual Studio 2017 Performance Profiler to debug the UI thread

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, performance, ui-thread

I am developing a desktop app in WPF and .Net Framework. I am experiencing apparently random UI Freezes of few seconds.

I run the Performance Profiler of Visual Studio and I can see that there are time spans where the FPS drop to zero:

[image]

By seeing those green bars, I thought that I would be able to find out who is blocking the UI thread but there's a gap in the timeline:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion to help me find out who is causing those blocks?
It is also the first time that I am using the tool, so I might missing something in the setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the gap co-incides with the drop in FPS?  That happens, tells you that it isn't your code that is causing this.  Next is to temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  Next is to look at network traffic with TCPView.

Comment: Yes, it coincides. The app also communicate with a PLC via Ethernet. All the communications should be on separate threads tho. That's probably what I should investigate